# Using SyncLock to synchronize access to List(of T)

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, locking, synclock

I have a class that contains a List(of T) used in a multithreaded application.  I have three methods Get, Add and Remove where these access and modify the List(of T).  I was using SyncLock to lock m_List any time I queried it for the desired object as well as when I added or removed objects.  **However I'm curious as to if there is a performance gain by simply locking m_List when I add an object or remove an object as opposed to when I'm searching for a desired object?**

```
Public Shared sub Add(SomeObject as object)

     SyncLock ctype(m_List, IList).SyncRoot

         m_List.add(SomeObject)

     end SyncLock

end sub

Public Shared sub Remove(SearchString as string)

     SyncLock ctype(m_List, IList).SyncRoot

           m_List.RemoveAll(function(o as SomeObject) o.SomeProperty = SearchString)

     end SyncLock
end Function

Public Shared Function Get(SearchString as string) as SomeObject
     'The Commented out code is what I am thinking of removing...
     'SyncLock ctype(m_List, IList).SyncRoot

     Dim FoundObjectList = m_List.where(function(o as SomeObject) o.SomeProperty = SearchString)

    if FoundObjectList.count > 0 then 

       If FoundObjectList(0).CreateDate < Now.AddMinutes(5) then
          Remove(FoundObjectList(0).SomeProperty)
          Return nothing
       end if
    else
         Return FoundObjectList(0)

    End if

   Return Nothing
'end SyncLock
end sub
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you try to iterate over the list and allow another thread to add an entry while you're doing so, you'll get an `InvalidOperationException`, it's as simple as that. My guess is that's not the behaviour you want.

`List<T>` simply doesn't support writing from one thread and reading from another at the same time - particularly not iterating over the list.

Comment: so I take it I need to lock the list while the iteration is taking place, i.e. any linq queries I'm running against the collection?

Comment: @Achilles: Either lock it for the whole iteration time, or take a copy within a lock and iterate over the copy.